# Can you add a .then to a promise after it's created?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Promises just baffle me.

I'm trying to make a mock data service to imitate axios.

My mock `put` call passes a targetUrl to `_fetch` which then sees if it's a valid url and either returns a new Promise with a delayed .resolve

```
const _returnResponse = (mockData, time = 0) => new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(mockData);
    }, time);
});
```

or a new Promise with a delayed .reject

```
const _returnError = (time = simulatedDelay) => {
    const returnValue = new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            reject(new Error('error'));
        }, time);
    }));
    return returnValue;
};
```

but when I make my mock `put` call this returns a mock data that the calling method interprets as a success and console logs in its .then

```
    put(target, putBody) {
        const returnValue = _fetch(target, simulatedDelay)
        returnValue.then(response => _console('PUT', target, response, putBody));
        return returnValue;
    },
```

But with an invalid target console logs an uncaught error

or this handles the error correctly, but console logs an undefined response

```
    put(target, putBody) {
        const returnValue = _fetch(target, simulatedDelay).then(response => _console('PUT', target, response, putBody));
        return returnValue;
    },
```

Here's the calling method:

```
    saveStuff({ commit, state }, newStuff) {
        //other code

        return this.$mockAxios.put(url, putBody)
            .then((response) => {
                return response;
            });
    },
```

I feel like I'm completely missing something and I've researched this for hours and I'm still not getting it.

Comment: Having some difficulty in understanding what you're trying to do with your code.
Might be worth putting an isolated code into JSFiddle or similar code playground services. Otherwise, if you have access to ES7/babel, you might be better off using async functions with the `async` and `await` keywords, which makes async programming much easier and simple.

Comment: I'm not certain how to handle you precise issue -- but with regard to your comment "Promises just baffle me", I found this tutorial helpful: https://medium.com/@rafaelvidaurre/truly-understanding-async-await-491dd580500e

Comment: This was so helpful. I may update with a fiddle at some point with my specific problem, but pointing me in the direction of more learning is what I really needed. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a direct answer to the question: yes, you can add .then() to a promise after it's created.

Example:

```
const hi = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve('hello'), 2000);
});

hi.then(result => console.log(result));
```

As for promises baffling you, I would recommend (aside from more reading) just playing around a lot in your IDE with setTimeout. I know you're already using setTimeout in your mock, but strip it down further and just run the code in its own file, so that you control the whole environment. With lots of console.log('blah') to see the order and such. Also ensure you're just as familiar with callbacks, as promises are just syntactic sugar for callbacks. Try to read up on the JS event loop at the same time - it might provide some context if you know how and when a callback/promise executes.

Note that you can even add .then() after the callback has resolved or rejected. Hence the term "promise" - it's literally a promise that your .then() function will run. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promise_theory

```
const hi = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('one second');
    resolve();
  }, 1000);
});

setTimeout(() => {
  hi.then(() => console.log('two seconds. this executes approximately a full second after the first promise has resolved'));
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Thank you so much James. I'll take some time and research those topics and then simplify it the way you're suggesting. The problem I was having was running out of online resources and still not understanding them.